# PhpStorm warning on HTML comment

Tags: html, phpstorm, warnings, webstorm

- PHP 8.0
- PhpStorm 2021.2
- Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1504.13 amd64
- Windows 10

I am receiving warnings "Selector matches unknown element suppress" and "Selector matches unknown element JSUnresolvedLibraryURL" in PhpStorm for the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?=$title?></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="Description" content="Real Estate for sale <?=$fullAddress?>. MLS <?=$MLS?>">
    <!--suppress JSUnresolvedLibraryURL -->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
</head>
```

It runs without error, but I would like to understand the why behind the warning and resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must have some language [injected](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-language-injections.html#Using_Language_Injections.xml) in the comments. Please check language injections with `IDE` and `Project` scopes in **Preferences | Editor | Language Injections**.